# Resizing a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout, dimensions

I was wondering how I can resize the 'alarmClockButton' in my code, I've tried setSize(); and setPreferredSize(); however they both don't work. I am using the GridBagLayout for this. Any ideas?

```
 public class MainMenu {

    // JFrame = the actual menu / frame.
    private JFrame frame;
    // JLabel = provides text instructions or information on a GUI —
    // display a single line of read-only text, an image or both text and an image.
    private JLabel background, logo;
    // JButton = button.
    private JButton alarmClockButton;

    // Constructor to create menu
    public MainMenu() {
        frame = new JFrame("Alarm Clock");
        alarmClockButton = new JButton("Timer");
        alarmClockButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        // Add an event to clicking the button.
        alarmClockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO: CHANGE TO SOMETHING NICER
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This feature hasn't been implemented yet.", "We're sorry!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        // Creating the background
        try {
            background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass()
                    .getResourceAsStream("/me/devy/alarm/clock/resources/background.jpg"))));
            logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass()
            .getResourceAsStream("/me/devy/alarm/clock/resources/logo.png"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(background);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        // Inset = spacing between each component
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15, 15, 15);
        // Positioning
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(logo, gbc);
        // Positioning
        // Keep x the same = aligned. On same x-coordinate (think math!)
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        // Y = 2 down
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(alarmClockButton, gbc);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(550, 200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        alarmClockButton.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are you actually getting? More pertinent description would help a great deal.

Comment: Resizing a button is best done using a different sized font or different length text, by changing the size of the icon, or by changing the margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can effect the size of the button through the `GridBagConstraints`, for example...

Using `ipadx` and `ipady`, which add to the components `preferredSize`

```
gbc.ipadx = 100;
gbc.ipady = 100;
```

Produces something like...

[image]

You can also use...

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

which changes the amount of space which the component will occupy and how the component is filled within it's given cell...

[image: Clock]

**Note:**

Because you're using a `JLabel` as your background component, you will be limited to the the label's preferred size, which is calculated through the `icon` and `text` properties only, it won't use the layout manager to calculate these results.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. Last queston, (not sure if I should put this in a different thread) but when I open the program the button is on the center of the GUI, how can I make it to the left? I tried making gridx a negative, but that gave me an ArraysOutOfBountException.

Comment: You could use the `anchor` property of `GridBagConstraints`, but I wouldn't use the `fill` property in that case